# Grouping/sorting performance choice between bigint and nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to store a hash-code for a variable-length text field (max 1000 chars) in a database table. The hash-code will be computed and assigned once on insert, and new rows will be inserted very often.

The hash-code will be used mainly for filtering (`WHERE`), grouping (`GROUP BY`), and sorting (`ORDER BY`) in a couple of queries. The database table will hold a few million rows over time, with the probability of identical hash-codes (for identical text) being around 30% (rest being unique).

I have the choice of making the hash-code data type `NVARCHAR` (SHA1 of text) or `BIGINT` (converted bytes of SHA1 of text). I think `BIGINT` will be better in terms of storage space (less pages).

Generally speaking, which of these two data types will be better in terms of performance, considering the operations mentioned above?

Comment: What did your tests show?

Comment: SHA1 hash values are 20 bytes (160 bits) long. There's no way you can fit that into a `bigint` which is 8 bytes long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to store the hash using the densest datatype possible.

A `bigint` is 8 bytes, or 64-bits of data.
An `nvarchar` storing 8 bytes of data would take 10 bytes on disk.

But how long are your hashes? SHA-1 hashes are 20 bytes long (160 bits) so won't fit in a `bigint`. Storing it as an `nvarchar` will take 42 bytes of storage if stored naively.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16680423/391445 you best option is to use `binary(20)` so you are storing exactly 20 bytes (160 bits) of data.

Are you intending to do the hashing in the database or in client code? According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), as of SQL Server 2016 all hash algorithms other than SHA2_256 and SHA2_512 are deprecated.

But a cryptographic hash function is probably not the best choice of hash function for you if all you want is a random distribution of rows. There are many hash functions available, producing whatever length key you desire!

Comment: That's a valid point. SHA-1 won't be a good fit for `BIGINT`. Someone suggested XORing 8-bytes chunks of a SHA-256 hash (32 bytes), but it being a crypto algorithm may be an overkill for my use case. I was thinking of using a non-crypto hash like murmur or xxhash, which will generate a 64-bit integer. If using `binary(20)` like you suggest then I'm not sure how functional and performant will the filtering/grouping/sorting operations be.

Comment: Should be fine, presuming the columns are indexed the same.

Comment: Tested both data types in a test table with 100k rows: `binary(20)` (SHA1) vs `bigint` (XORed 8-bytes chunks of SHA-256), with clustered-indexes on both fields. Execution plan suggests than grouping operation on `bigint` has around 10% less cost (in index scan) than `binary`. But `binary` hash storage seems simpler because it can be done in SQL Server or client (.NET). Non-crypto hashing may result in collisions. I'll run some more tests, and share any interesting results.

Comment: Correction: meant non-clustered indexes above.

Comment: Please don't assume anything about the performance of this operation based on the estimated costs.  The costing functions are really geared more towards the relational operators (join, group by, etc) and not as much towards the scalars since they are often much cheaper.  Please do an experiment with real data.  Some customers have done filtering on pre-computed hashes like this, but it's usually only high-end customers who would ever have the scale or need.  In any event, binary(20) is faster at comparisons than most nvarchar since binary compare is faster than collation compare

Comment: Thanks Conor and Colin. I tried it with near-real test data (100k URLs). The 10% difference in query cost is for the `group by` operation. I'm sure `binary` is more compact and faster than `nvarchar` in relational operations, but `binary` is slightly slower than `bigint` in my grouping tests, which is also the most compact (8 bytes). Having said that, I understand than `binary` is probably best suited for hashes, as I couldn't find a reliable hash than fits in 8-bytes without collisions.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll go with a fixed-length `binary` column as it's the ideal way to store hash bytes, and supports indexing too. The only thing I'm unsure about is if storage or performance will be impacted due to index fragmentation as hash bytes will vary a lot from each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to go the route of BIGINT and accomplish what you need then that would be my preference. It'll be more performant for the SQL Server Engine to sort, filter, and join on as opposed to NVARCHAR because of the numeric type and the smaller size of the data value, and as you mentioned will technically take up less space (theoretically also allowing your table's data pages to load into memory quicker - though this is probably a negligible difference on the whole for only a few million rows).